# Connecting between Python and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I'm setting up a new server, and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application. I use python for the server and JavaScript for the client. I want to know if there are build-in functions to pass between short to bytes in both languages like the fuction i attached (its in C++). More important for me is to know how to send and get bytes from a socket on both languages.

`void ConnectionHandler::shortToBytes(short num, char *bytesArr) {
    bytesArr[0] = ((num >> 8) & 0xFF);
    bytesArr[1] = (num & 0xFF);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Short answers to your Python side of questions is to use ctypes(https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module for the conversion of a byte to a short, and the socket module for server handling(https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html).

As for the javascript side I can't really help there.